# How to reload an image from the same path without refreshing the page?

Tags: python, jquery, html, ajax, flask

I'm trying to load an image file with flask, and then update the same file with a different image and display the newly updated image without having to refresh the page.

I've tried different combinations with ajax and jquery and none have worked so far but it is possible I'm just missing a really simple fix.

This is the index.html file I currently have

```
    <script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div>
        <img id="my_image" src = "{{img}}">
    </div>
<script>
    function getimg(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        url: "{{url_for('get_img')}}", 
        success: function(resp){
            dt = new Date();
            $('my_image').attr('src', resp.img + "?" + dt.getTime());
        }
    }); 
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(getimg, 3000);
    });       
    </script>

</body>
```

And this is the flask routes from getImage.py

```
import json
from flask import render_template


@app.route('/img')
def open_image():
    img = 'static\\testing.jpg'
    return render_template('index.html',**locals())

@app.route('/get_img', methods = ['GET'])
def get_img():
    img = 'static\\testing.jpg'
    return json.dumps({img:img})
```

I know the ajax is sending requests through to flask via cmd but it does not actually update the image.

Comment: `$('my_image').attr('src', resp.img + "?" + dt.getTime());` should be `$('#my_image').attr('src', resp.img + "?" + dt.getTime());` - you are missing the jQuery `id` selector `#`

Comment: @Steve thanks, I missed that.  It now works except when it reloads I get a 404 error code GET undefined and the image changes to the small image icon.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know anything about python sorry. I would check that the generated HTML is all OK though (the ajax URL part especially). I did notice that both routes return the same image? - so you might not see the image actually change.

Comment: @Steve correct, ideally I want to save over the same image and update only that image, but for testing purposes I've temporarily added a second image just to notice if it actually does change.  Thanks for the help and input though :)

Comment: UPDATE: Got it! Turns out I was also missing quotes around img in json.dumps({'img':img}) which I also switched to jsonify anyways

Comment: Glad to hear it's all sorted now.